# Empty $OPTARG with getopts "b:" and ''./script -b foo''

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I'm trying to create a bash file that will accept command line parameters, but my OPTARG isn't producing any result, which it appears is necessary to get this to work?

Here is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts ":b" opt; do
  case $opt in
    b)  
        echo "result is: $OPTARG";;
    \?) 
        echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2;;  
  esac
done
```

When I run that with: `file.sh -b TEST`, this is the result I get: `result is:`

Any ideas what is going on here?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're missing a colon after `b` (not needed before `b`).

Use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts "b:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    b)  
        echo "result is: $OPTARG";;
    *) 
        echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2;;  
  esac
done
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm blaming the tutorial I used since I copied their code directly :) This fixed the issue and I'm off and running!

Comment: This would have been complete with an explanation of what exactly the colon does. It doesn't help that the documentation for the getopts string is basically black magic and not easily explained anywhere.